# Posts display, but don't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting out with RoR and have been having a great time so far. Currently I'm trying to post events to a central feed and perhaps I have envisioned how I'm setting things up incorrectly. I have two models, Users and Events, I'll give a gist. Users have_many events, while Events belong_to Users. I'm trying to save events to a central feed "ala facebook" that is visible by all Users. My Create Method in the Event controller is:

```
def create
@event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
if @event.save
  flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
  render :action => :show 
else
  render :new
end
end
```

render :action => :show is diplaying the post and going to /events but the post is not being saved. And when I go back to /events I get the error: Couldn't find Event without an ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, the rails community has been great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your source code and see currently the following things I don't think are correct. If they are responsible for the not-storing of events, I do not know:

1. Your routes.rb file has some things I don't understand:

   - If events `belongs_to` users, and users has many events, events should stay in the context of users. See [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in the Rails Guides. Your definition for urls there could be

     ```
     resources :users do
       resources :events
     ```
   - Your additional match rule `match '/events',  :to => 'events#show'` is dangerous, because it overwrites the normal index route. Where will the id of the event you want to show come from?
2. File `events_controller.rb`

   - In the `EventsController#create` method, where does that `current_user` comes from?
   - in your path `if @event.save` you do at the end `render :action => :show`. This will

     - show the wrong view (not the index but the show page of your events controller.
     - will not call the action before.

     Normal usage here is, that you use `redirect_to @event` which will use the correct action and show the correct view.

I will not go any further, but I would change these two files first. Are you sure that your `@event` was not saved? How about adding `puts` statements in the path, like that:

```
if @event.save
  flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
  redirect_to @event # or use redirect_to(events_url)
else
  puts "Failure in storing: #{@event}"
  flash[:failure] = "Event not shared."
  render :new
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I was looking into it and I'm incorrect, the events are being saved to db, but not being displayed. Thank you for pointing me to this nested resources.